# java - After the exception handling ends and correctly, switch code is executed in a never ending loop.

Tags: java, error-handling, switch-statement

First of all, thank you for reading this post. 
I have this case of exception handling followed by a switch. After the exception handling ends correctly, the switch code is executed in a never-ending loop. If I comment the exception handling part and just add 
"selection = scanner.nextInt()" the code works fine. But with the exception handling, never-ending loop happens again. I am quite sure it is all about the position of the curly braces but I just can't sort out which of them. 
Thank you for help on this.

import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    ToString human = new ToString("John", 30, true);

    int selection = 0;
    boolean quit = false;
    String selecta = null;
    String message = "Select option";

    while (!quit) {
        returnMessage(message);
        while (selecta == null) {

            try {
                selecta = scanner.nextLine();
                selection = Integer.valueOf(selecta);
                break;

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                returnMessage("An integer was expected. Please try again.");
                selecta = null;
                returnMessage(message);
            }
        }
                switch (selection) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println(human.getAge());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println(human.getName());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println(human.isMan());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        quit = true;
                        break;

                }
    }
}

public static void returnMessage (String message){
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you debug it? Step through this in a debugger, you'll see what happens after breaks etc.
As your question stands now you're simply asking someone to debug this for you. Either mentally or in an IDE. Please do it yourself.

Comment: `scanner.nextLine()` might return `null`, which will cause `NumberFormatException` to be thrown from `Integer.parse`, which will happen *before* `selection` variable assigned. Also, the condition of continuing the loop is that `selecta` is `null`. So, if there is no more lines in input, your code will indeed spiral into an infinite loop. You need to rethink how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`selecta` variable never gets set to null after the switch statement and since your input is in a block with a condition `selecta == null`it never executes and goes straight back into the switch statement, and so on, and so on...

Put `selecta = null` after the switch statement and that should be it.

Comment: Np, but do heed the advice the others gave you in comments, use the debug feature!